# Actions passed as props in Redux connected component are not called when form submit is simulated during testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I'm testing my first app and I've been having issues testing a Redux connected component.

More specifically I'm testing `Search.js`. The idea is simulating a form submission in the child component `DisplaySearcgBar.js` and then test if `setAlert` and `getRestaurants` are called.

In test #3 since the inputs are empty when the form is submitted `Search.js` should call `OnSubmit()` which should call `setAlert` and in #4 it should call `getRestaurants` since inputs are provided.

Both tests are rejected with the same error:

```
Search › 3 - setAlert called if search button is pressed with no input

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      37 |     wrapper.find('[data-test="search"]').simulate('click');
      38 |     //expect(store.getActions().length).toBe(1);
    > 39 |     expect(wrapper.props().children.props.props.setAlert).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |                                                           ^
      40 |   });
      41 | 
      42 |   test('4 - getRestaurant called when inputs filled and search button clicked ', () => {

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Components/restaurants/Search/__tests__/Search.test.js:39:59)

  ● Search › 4 - getRestaurant called when inputs filled and search button clicked 

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      55 |     wrapper.find('[data-test="search"]').simulate('click');
      56 | 
    > 57 |     expect(wrapper.props().children.props.props.getRestaurants).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |                                                                 ^
      58 |   });
      59 | });
      60 | 

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Components/restaurants/Search/__tests__/Search.test.js:57:65)
```

I'm new to testing and I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong.

I tried different approaches with how to select both functions but either I was getting the same error above or it couldn't find them.
I feel like I'm running in circles, I must be missing something but I don't understand what.

Here's Search.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import Search from './../Search';
import DisplaySearchBar from '../../../layout/DisplaySearchBar/DisplaySearchBar';

const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);
const initialState = {
  restaurants: { restaurants: ['foo'], alert: null },
};
const store = mockStore(initialState);
const mockSetAlert = jest.fn();
const mockGetRestaurants = jest.fn();
const onSubmit = jest.fn();
const wrapper = mount(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Search setAlert={mockSetAlert} getRestaurants={mockGetRestaurants} />
  </Provider>
);

describe('Search', () => {
  /* beforeEach(() => {
    const form = wrapper.find('form').first();
    form.simulate('submit', {
      preventDefault: () => {},
    });
  }); */

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test('1 - renders without errors', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(DisplaySearchBar)).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  test('2 - if restaurants clearButton is rendered', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('[data-test="clear"]')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  test('3 - setAlert called if search button is pressed with no input', () => {
    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', { preventDefault: () => {} });

    expect(mockSetAlert).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  test('4 - getRestaurant called when inputs filled and search button clicked ', () => {
    wrapper
      .find('[name="where"]')
      .at(0)
      .simulate('change', { target: { value: 'foo' } });

    wrapper
      .find('[name="what"]')
      .at(0)
      .simulate('change', { target: { value: 'foo' } });

    wrapper
      .find('[data-test="best_match"]')
      .at(0)
      .simulate('click');

    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', { preventDefault: () => {} });

    expect(mockGetRestaurants).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      name: 'foo',
      where: 'foo',
      sortBy: 'best_match',
    });
  });
});
```

Search.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { handleScriptLoad } from '../../../helpers/Autocomplete';
import { getRestaurants, setAlert } from '../../../actions/restaurantAction';
import DisplaySearchBar from '../../layout/DisplaySearchBar/DisplaySearchBar';

import styles from './Search.module.scss';

const Search = ({ getRestaurants, setAlert }) => {
  const [where, setWhere] = useState('');
  const [what, setWhat] = useState('');
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState('rating');

  const sortByOptions = {
    'Highest Rated': 'rating',
    'Best Match': 'best_match',
    'Most Reviewed': 'review_count',
  };

  // give active class to option selected
  const getSortByClass = (sortByOption) => {
    if (sortBy === sortByOption) {
      return styles.active;
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  };

  // set the state of a sorting option
  const handleSortByChange = (sortByOption) => {
    setSortBy(sortByOption);
  };

  //handle input changes
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === 'what') {
      setWhat(e.target.value);
    } else if (e.target.name === 'where') {
      setWhere(e.target.value);
    }
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (where && what) {
      getRestaurants({ where, what, sortBy });
      setWhere('');
      setWhat('');
      setSortBy('best_match');
    } else {
      setAlert('Please fill all the inputs');
    }
  };

  // displays sort options
  const renderSortByOptions = () => {
    return Object.keys(sortByOptions).map((sortByOption) => {
      let sortByOptionValue = sortByOptions[sortByOption];
      return (
        <li
          className={`${sortByOptionValue} ${getSortByClass(
            sortByOptionValue
          )}`}
          data-test={sortByOptionValue}
          key={sortByOptionValue}
          onClick={() => handleSortByChange(sortByOptionValue)}
        >
          {sortByOption}
        </li>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <DisplaySearchBar
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      handleChange={handleChange}
      renderSortByOptions={renderSortByOptions}
      where={where}
      what={what}
      handleScriptLoad={handleScriptLoad}
    />
  );
};

Search.propTypes = {
  getRestaurants: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  setAlert: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default connect(null, { getRestaurants, setAlert })(Search);
```

Its child component where the button is

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { clearSearch } from '../../../actions/restaurantAction';
//Import React Script Libraray to load Google object
import Script from 'react-load-script';
import Fade from 'react-reveal/Fade';
import Alert from '../Alert/Alert';

import styles from './DisplaySearchBar.module.scss';

const DisplaySearchBar = ({
  renderSortByOptions,
  onSubmit,
  where,
  handleChange,
  what,
  handleScriptLoad,
  restaurants,
  clearSearch,
}) => {
  const googleUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY}&libraries=places`;
  // {googleUrl && <Script url={googleUrl} onLoad={handleScriptLoad} />}
  return (
    <section className={styles.searchBar}>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className={styles.searchBarForm}>
        <legend className="title">
          <Fade left>
            <h1>Where are you going to eat tonight?</h1>
          </Fade>
        </legend>
        <Fade>
          <fieldset className={styles.searchBarInput}>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="where"
              placeholder="Where do you want to eat?"
              value={where}
              onChange={handleChange}
              id="autocomplete"
            />

            <input
              type="text"
              name="what"
              placeholder="What do you want to eat?"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={what}
            />
            <div data-test="alert-holder" className={styles.alertHolder}>
              <Alert />
            </div>
          </fieldset>

          <fieldset className={styles.searchBarSubmit}>
            <input
              data-test="search"
              className={`${styles.myButton} button`}
              type="submit"
              name="submit"
              value="Search"
            ></input>

            {restaurants.length > 0 && (
              <button
                data-test="clear"
                className={`${styles.clearButton} button`}
                onClick={clearSearch}
              >
                Clear
              </button>
            )}
          </fieldset>
        </Fade>
      </form>
      <article className={styles.searchBarSortOptions}>
        <Fade>
          <ul>{renderSortByOptions()}</ul>
        </Fade>
      </article>
    </section>
  );
};

DisplaySearchBar.propTypes = {
  renderSortByOptions: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  where: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  what: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  handleScriptLoad: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  restaurants: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  clearSearch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStatetoProps = (state) => ({
  restaurants: state.restaurants.restaurants,
});

export default connect(mapStatetoProps, { clearSearch })(DisplaySearchBar);
```

RestaurantActions.js

```
import { getCurrentPosition } from '../helpers/GeoLocation';
import {
  getRestaurantsHelper,
  getRestaurantsInfoHelper,
  getDefaultRestaurantsHelper,
} from '../helpers/utils';

import {
  CLEAR_SEARCH,
  SET_LOADING,
  GET_LOCATION,
  SET_ALERT,
  REMOVE_ALERT,
} from './types';

// Get Restaurants
export const getRestaurants = (text) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setLoading());

  getRestaurantsHelper(text, dispatch);
};

// Get Restaurants Info
export const getRestaurantInfo = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setLoading());
  getRestaurantsInfoHelper(id, dispatch);
};

// Get default restaurants
export const getDefaultRestaurants = (location, type) => async (dispatch) => {
  if (location.length > 0) {
    getDefaultRestaurantsHelper(location, type, dispatch);
  }
};

// Get location
export const fetchCoordinates = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { coords } = await getCurrentPosition();
    dispatch({
      type: GET_LOCATION,
      payload: [coords.latitude.toFixed(5), coords.longitude.toFixed(5)],
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(setAlert('Location not available'));
  }
};

// Set loading
export const setLoading = () => ({ type: SET_LOADING });

// Clear search
export const clearSearch = () => ({ type: CLEAR_SEARCH });

// Set alert
export const setAlert = (msg, type) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: SET_ALERT,
    payload: { msg, type },
  });

  setTimeout(() => dispatch({ type: REMOVE_ALERT }), 5000);
};
```

Here's the full repository on Github: https://github.com/mugg84/RestaurantFinderRedux.git

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I fount out how to test if `setAlert` and `getRestaurants` are called.
I used the `Search` that is exposed as default instead of using the raw component.

So even if I gave it `setAlert` and `getRestaurants` props, the connect method of the default component was overriding it and gave it's own `setAlert` and `getRestaurants`, that's why they were never called.

The raw component is not Redux-aware, it just gets props from the Redux store and use them. As the testing needs to be focused on the raw component and not the store, we need to export it in isolation for the testing.

I still use the `mockstore` for when `DisplaySearchBar` is rendered.

As I mentioned before in `Search.js` I export the raw component:

```
  // previous code
export const Search = ({ getRestaurants, setAlert }) => {
   // rest of the code
```

And by testing it instead of the default component I just have to check if the `setAlert` and `getRestaurants` passed as mockfunctions are being called. (test # 3 and #4)

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import { Search as BaseSearch } from './../Search';
import { DisplaySearchBar as BaseDisplaySearchBar } from '../../../layout/DisplaySearchBar/DisplaySearchBar';

const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);
const initialState = {
  restaurants: { restaurants: ['foo'], alert: null },
};

const getRestaurants = jest.fn();
const setAlert = jest.fn();

let wrapper, store;

describe('Search', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore(initialState);

    wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BaseSearch setAlert={setAlert} getRestaurants={getRestaurants} />
      </Provider>
    );
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test('1 - renders without errors', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(BaseDisplaySearchBar)).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  test('2 - if restaurants clearButton is rendered', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('[data-test="clear"]')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  test('3 - setAlert called if search button is pressed with no input', () => {
    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', { preventDefault: () => {} });

    expect(setAlert).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  test('4 - getRestaurants called when inputs filled and search button clicked ', () => {
    wrapper
      .find('[name="where"]')
      .at(0)
      .simulate('change', { target: { value: 'foo', name: 'where' } });

    wrapper
      .find('[name="what"]')
      .at(0)
      .simulate('change', { target: { value: 'foo', name: 'what' } });

    wrapper
      .find('[data-test="best_match"]')
      .at(0)
      .simulate('click');

    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', { preventDefault: () => {} });

    expect(getRestaurants).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Search.js is a connected component. Its props are coming from the store through mapDispatchToProps. Even if you mock the props, the generated wrapper takes the respective functions from the provider's store. So the solution is to check whether the actions have been called with the required type and payload.

Another issue in test-4 is you are not passing `name` inside `event`. Hence the values were not getting set in the state. To avoid such situations, use the console to debug your tests.

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import Search from './../Search';
import DisplaySearchBar from '../../../layout/DisplaySearchBar/DisplaySearchBar';

import {
  SET_LOADING,
  SET_ALERT,

} from '../../../../actions/types';

const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);
const initialState = {
  restaurants: { restaurants: ['foo'], alert: null },
};
const store = mockStore(initialState);
const mockSetAlert = jest.fn();
const mockGetRestaurants = jest.fn();

const wrapper = mount(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Search setAlert={mockSetAlert} getRestaurants={mockGetRestaurants} />
  </Provider>
);

describe('Search', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test('1 - renders without errors', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(DisplaySearchBar)).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  test('2 - if restaurants clearButton is rendered', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('[data-test="clear"]')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  test('3 - setAlert called if search button is pressed with no input', () => {
    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', { preventDefault: () => {} });
    const actions= store.getActions();
    const expected={
      type: SET_ALERT,
      payload: expect.objectContaining({msg:"Please fill all the inputs"})
    };
    expect(actions[0]).toMatchObject(expected);
  });

  test('4 - getRestaurant called when inputs filled and search button clicked ', () => {
    wrapper
      .find('[name="where"]')
      .at(0)
      .simulate('change', { target: { value: 'foo', name:"where" } });

    wrapper
      .find('[name="what"]')
      .at(0)
      .simulate('change', { target: { value: 'foo',name:"what" } });

    wrapper
      .find('[data-test="best_match"]')
      .at(0)
      .simulate('click');

    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', { preventDefault: () => {} });
    const actions= store.getActions();
    const expected={
      type: SET_LOADING,
    };
    expect(actions).toContainEqual(expected);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because enzyme's `find()` returns a collection of html nodes.

Remember this good old enzyme's error?

> Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node.

Try it like so: `wrapper.find('...').at(0)`.

Also, when you expect your mocked ’setAlert()`and`getRestaurant()`to have been called, you refer to them in a way that unables us to know if it's a right or wrong reference. So, please supply your relevant`debug()` results, or, better, mock them like so:

```
const mockSetAlert = jest.fn();
const mockGetRestaurants = jest.fn();

const wrapper = mount(
    <Search setAlert={mockSetAlert} getRestaurants={mockGetRestaurants} />
);

...

expect(mockSetAlert).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(mockGetRestaurants).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

It's a simplified example, but you get the idea...

Comment: @k-wasilewsky I've tried it but I get the same error as before..

Comment: @k-wasilewsky I did as suggested, (in the wrapper I had to keep the ``` <Provider store={store}>``` if not I was getting an error), but nothing changed. Still same errors.

Comment: Of course. How about changing it to `const Search = (props) => {...}` and accessing the functions like `props.setAlert()` ?

Comment: @k-wasilewsky Already tried to access them like that but same errors

Comment: Ok, so I'm not sure you can simulate a 'click' on an input. In this case the more correct approach would be to `wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit')`

Comment: @k-wasilewsky Not even simulating the form submission triggers the functions ```wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit');                                              
    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', { preventDefault: () => {},});

    expect(mockSetAlert).toHaveBeenCalled();```

Comment: Well then, somewhere in your function calls' chain there is a bug, so try to debug every function from button click to your `setAlert` and see where the issue lies...